# Defining a route inside a lumen package

Tags: lumen

I'm working on a Lumen package. In this package I have to define 2 routes for webhooks. What I did is create a routes file, load that through `loadRoutesFrom()` in my package's service provider, and in the routes file, I defined the route like this:

```
$this->app->get("/webhooks/decision", \YoungOnes\ArtisanVeriff\Commands\DecisionWebhookCommand::class);
```

I saw this in an article somewhere as a valid solution, especially since I can't use the routes class. However, when I run this, I get the following:

```
EntryNotFoundException
/webhooks/decision
```

How do I define a route from within a Lumen package?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this - it seems to work:

```
$this->app->router->get()
```